# TextView change DrawableLeft in ListView

Tags: android, listview, textview, drawable

I have ArrayList which is load simple xml textview as item. In the TextView i have drawableleft, but i can`t figure it out, how to change that image? in adapter or? because there is now way out to insert drawable object in string list.

i have load items like:

```
items = new ArrayList<String>();
items.add(Some String item);
```

this is the adapter

```
ArrayAdapter<String> List = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item_text, items);
ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
mylist.setAdapter(List);
```

and my TextView item

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/item"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/folder"
android:drawableEnd="@drawable/next" >
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend the `ArrayAdapter` class and override the `getView()` method. This method returns the `View` that will be placed in each row while the data is loaded. Use it to change the image as you wish.

Comment: yes, it work fine. If someone need i can show the code method